# Have problems about mpi after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, cmake, mpi

I upgraded to 20.04 from 19.10. On 20.04, I encounter the problem that CMAKE cannot find MPI, which was not a problem on 19.10. By using my own makefile, ld cannot find lmpi neither. It seems that at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, there is a libmpi.so.40, but ld try to find libmpi.so. Copying the libmpi.so.40 to libmpi.so would make my own makefile work, but CMAKE still cannot find MPI. In addition, an error "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key" occurs when I run mpirun. Any suggestion?